# Error running simple Phonegap 3 application

Tags: cordova

I had developed applications with phonegap 2.x without problem. I tried to upgrade to version 3 by carefully following the installation steps and creating a starting Helloworld appication ( without adding anything or modifying source files). But I got a runtime error (on both virtual and real device) :

**There was a network error.
(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)**

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT

I works by replacing:

```
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
```

by

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-app-hello-world-3.2.0/www/index.html");
```

But the "Deviceready" event dont fire.
There is really an issue with Phonegap 3 project creation.

Comment: Check whether your www folder has index.html page or not

Comment: What is surprising is that the app files, including index.html, have been placed in (android\assets\www\phonegap-app-hello-world-3.2.0\www\) instead of (android\assets\www\)

Comment: Move the file to www location you will be good to move ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments move phonegap-app-hello-world-3.2.0\www contents to android\assets\www folder. You can set the start up page name in res/xml/config.xml

```
<content src="Login.html" />
```